# Navigator tab not seen in mysql workbench ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-16.04

It was there but accidently closed by me now I am unable to find that navigator where exists,I also checked in Edit->prefernece->SQL Editor and checked all sidebar action.apart from this in View->panels having  3 options
1) Hide sidebar
2) Hide secondary sidebar
3) Hide output Area

Answer (score 2):

It may be too simple for words but you also might try to drag the panel from the left. I had the same problem once and after trying all menus and proper settings, this worked for me in the end... so it was actually there all the time. :)